# Should concrete service depend on concrete repository or interface?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I've struggled with implementing repository and service patterns for a while while using ASP.net MVC and Entity Framework.

I understand the purpose of the repository pattern and how it helps with testing and makes the data layer interchangeable. However, Entity Framework is already a repository/unit of work pattern. Every implementation of the repository pattern that I've seen either strips EF of it's useful features or implements an `IQueryable<T>` property that makes the purists squirm.

If I'm writing interfaces for my service layer, then implementing concrete versions of those services is there a reason I should not just use Entity Framework as my data layer directly in the service (as opposed to wrapping it in a repository/unit of work pattern and injecting the dependency)? For example: can't I create an `IService` interface, then create a concrete `EfService` (Entity Framework) or `NhService` (NHibernate version) implementations?

I can then use my IoC container to inject the desired service and data contexts.

---

Here is an example of what I have come up with based on Sergey's comments: https://github.com/sweeperq/Monona

Is that how the pattern is meant to be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always go with repository interfaces.

First reason is testability - `DbContext` and `DbSet<T>` are hard to mock. So, unit-testing of services becomes really hard, if even possible.

Second reason is `IQueryable<T>` being exposed by EF. It makes data-access logic spread over whole application, which violates SRP and makes fixing issues harder.

Third reason might be not very important - ability to switch interface implementations - not only with real object and mock, but with different data-access framework. You always think - "no, I definitely will stick with EF". But in real world I have experience of switching to Dapper due to performance issues and ease of development. And once I had experience of switching from in-memory data storage to EF. So, it's always nice to have that option instead of depending on framework-specific API.

Fourth reason is nice domain-specific API which repositories give you. Instead of having something like `db.Orders.Where(o => o.Category == "Food")` you have nice method `repository.GetOrdersByCategory`.

Another reason is that you have data-access logic in one place. No duplication. In sample above you can have five places in your application which use same query to filter orders by category. With repository you will have single method for that, which will be called in five places. Consider what if your business rules will change? E.g. you will need also to check if category is active.

Also keep in mind - once you have UoW and Repository base classes and interfaces, you can reuse them in different projects.

Comment: Sergey, why do you need to mock the `DbContext` and `DbSet<T>`? Can't you just mock the Service? Forgive me if I seem naive. I've tried to understand this for a long time and just never understood the purpose. Hoping for clarity.

Comment: @Sam I'm talking about unit-testing of services (or other classes which depend on repositories)

Comment: Do you have any useful examples you can point me to? I'm struggling to see how the repositories make your services any easier to unit-test.

Comment: @Sam have you tried to unit-test services which depend on EF? :) If you have problems with mocking repository interface, then possibly you are returning `IQueryable` from repository. Switch to `IEnumerable` and you'll be happy

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer. I'm still not 100% convinced. 1) I still don't understand why I need to mock `DbContext` and `DbSet<T>`. 2) `IQueryable<T>` wouldn't be all over the place, just used within the service. 3) All of these abstractions are complicating things so much that it prevents progress on the project. I'm worried more about accomplishing my goal than what might happen in a couple years.

Comment: 4) I would have things like `service.GetOrdersByCategory` instead of creating it once in the repository and just writing a service method to wrap around it. 5) The data-access logic would be encapsulated in the services along with the biz rules. 6) I can also use EF in different projects.

Comment: @Sam 1) You do unit-testing on your projects? Some TDD maybe? Units should be tested in isolation. You can't use real database 2) Maybe you are very good with it. Usually developers tend to push IQueryable further to make paging/sorting etc easier. 3) I don't know what you are complicating. Repositories are very simple. They allow you to define API and move very fast. 4) I'm starting to think that your service is a repository actually. If not, then how do you handle case when service should use several entities from database, not just orders by category?

Comment: @Sam 5) When you say data-access logic *with* business rules, then you definitely violate SRP. You should modify your services both when data-access logic changes, and when business rules changes. It would be hell if you'll decide to switch to Dapper or NHibernate. 6) Didn't get your point here

Comment: I'm not going to lie, I'm new to mocking/unit testing. Why can't you use a real database in unit testing? Your mock may not be a relational database, but it is an in memory representation of one, is it not? I thought the point is that the persistence mechanism shouldn't matter?

I trust that Microsoft has done a better job programming and testing their Entity Framework repositories (DbSets) than I have mine. With regards to #5) how is using `repo.GetActiveEntities()` to access data really that different than `context.Entities.Where(x => Active)` in my service layer?

Comment: Can you point me to a public repo on GitHub, maybe I'd understand better if I could see an example. All the examples floating around in the .Net world seem to expose IQueryable or have leaky abstraction between the repository and service layers.

Comment: It seemed like an awful lot of work, but I think I finally put together a working Unit of Work/Repository/Service example with separation of concerns. Does this look like what you would expect? https://github.com/sweeperq/Monona

Comment: @Sam yes, exactly. That is simplest implementation of UoW and repositories, which can be used. Usually you would have also method `IEnumerable<T> GetAll()` in repository interface. If you have big count of entities (i.e. tables in database) then you can use reflection to instantiate repositories in UoW. Something like generic method `GetRepository<T>`. But I'd suggest to use simplest implementation for start, just as one you pointed

Comment: Thanks For you help Sergey. What would `GetRepository<T>` look like? Would it return `IRepository<T>` and the service would need to cast to `ICountryRepository` to use the type specific methods? Or do you write extension methods geared towards `Repository<Country>`